# Removing keys if they exist in values in map

Tags: java

I have a map where keys can also exist as one of the values. I need to remove these from values. I wrote a method that does what I need, it's just I have over 80 thousand of keys and it takes forever.

```
static void cleanSetMap(Map<String, Set<String>> inputMap){
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(inputMap.keySet());
    List<Set<String>> values = new ArrayList<>(inputMap.values());

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        String key = keys.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {
            Set<String> set = values.get(j);
            set.remove(key);
            values.set(j, set);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        inputMap.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
    }
```

}

Can this be done simpler or faster?

Comment: Do you need to remove key only from corresponding set of values or from every set of values?
If you have map [a => [a, b, d], b => [a, b, c]] should result be [a => [b, d], b => [a, c]] or [a => [d], b => [c]]?

Comment: result should be  [a => [d], b => [c]], I need to remove all keys from any sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement will remove any string that is a key in the map from any all sets that are values in it.

```
    inputMap.keySet().parallelStream().forEach(
         key -> inputMap.values().stream().forEach(set -> set.remove(key)));
```

This is just a parallel stream on all map entries, running another sequential stream on value sets to remove each key.

You may need to test the behavior of a parallel stream in this case. If value `Set` instances aren't thread-safe, perhaps you should rather call `inputMap.keySet().stream()...` (but in that case the inner stream can be made parallel (`key -> inputMap.values().parallelStream()...`) as `Set.remove` won't be called concurrently on any given map value)

Comment: I need it to remove all keys from any value set it may contain.

Comment: @J.Doe Edited answer

Comment: That's lightning fast compared to what I had :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your sample code, it seems you are looking for removal of  all keys from value set, even if they are not present in that key-value pair.

You can try :

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(inputMap.keySet());
List<Set<String>> values = new ArrayList<>(inputMap.values());
Iterator<Set<String>> itr = values.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    itr.next().removeAll(keys);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think another option would be the introduction of more helpful abstractions.

Meaning: instead of keeping a "raw" map of string and sets of strings, it might be helpful to use some sort of index for example.

As in: remember for each string in which set it is used. Instead of introducing the need to iterate all values in your large map.

The point is: if removing strings that are used as keys and within these value sets is a common operation, then you simply choose a data type that allows you to do that efficiently.

Or you step back even further. For example by using a full text search engine such as Solr. For sure such frameworks allow for efficient updates to really large indices.